# SET variable=table_column=expression in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, variables, sql-update

I have this query in an mssql stored procedure:

```
 UPDATE @tmp_aging
    SET @balance=balance=(CASE WHEN @partner_code<>partner_code THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(@balance,0) END)+ISNULL(debit,0)-ISNULL(credit,0),
        @partner_code=partner_code;
```

As you can see, the variable @balance gets updated from the balance column which gets updated from an expression that returns multiple rows.

In other words, we update the variable @balance and column balance at the same time for each row, at least thats how I think it works. To keep track of the 'Brought Forward' balance in accounting.

Anyways, 
I'm converting all the stored procedures into postgresql functions, so how do I do the same thing in postgresql?

Comment: Btw I tried to do it in postgresql, the variable @balance I changed the name into v_balance so that the compiler wouldnt get confused, it appears I cant follow up variables after the SET keyword.

Comment: Not familiar with MSSQL syntax, but I think you want something like `UPDATE ... RETURNING balance INTO v_balance`

Comment: Doesn't work, it would return all the rows into v_balance (which causes an error unless its a table).

Comment: You're definitely looking for `RETURNING [columns] INTO [variables]` feature. What is the problem?

Comment: It returns all the updated entries/rows into the variable and gives an error, I'm doing it like this:  `RETURNING balance into v_balance;`

Comment: I want something like: `RETURNING SUM(balance) into v_balance` but postgresql doesnt allow following up a SUM

Answer (score 0):

> *I want something like: RETURNING SUM(balance) into v_balance*

You can wrap the update in a CTE:

```
with updated as (
  update the_table
     set ...
  where ...
  returning balance
)
select sum(balance)
  into v_balance
from updated;
```

---

But, your original statement:

```
UPDATE @tmp_aging
    SET @balance=balance=(CASE WHEN ... END) .., 
        @partner_code=partner_code;
```

would **not** do an aggregation in SQL Server, so I am not sure that this is really what you want.